# Cant get ADAL interceptor to work in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, adal

We are using azure active directory authentication for our application.  I've included it in the SPA and I'm able to get it to work for logging in.  I get an oauth token and I'm able to store it and see it.

Microsoft's ADAL-Angular.js provides an interceptor so that the token can be added to all $http calls.  It is supposed to not require changes to the SPA to use it.  I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I register the provider in the app.js and push it to the $httpprovider (even though ADAL-Angular does).  Here is the code.

```
       var connectionsApp = angular.module('app',
['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies',
    'tc.views', 'tc-flightProcessing', 'tc-agent',  'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.tab.scroll', 'AdalAngular'])
   .run(run);
connectionsApp.config(['scrollableTabsetConfigProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', function(scrollableTabsetConfigProvider,$httpProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider){
  scrollableTabsetConfigProvider.setShowTooltips (true);
  scrollableTabsetConfigProvider.setTooltipLeftPlacement('bottom');
  scrollableTabsetConfigProvider.setTooltipRightPlacement('left');
    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
         {
            tenant: 'xxxxxxxxx-9fafd38f483f',
            clientId: 'xxx'
         }, $httpProvider);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ProtectedResourceInterceptor');
 }]);
```

Here is the service call.

```
               var getDelayCodes = function () {
                if (isPromisePending) {
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
                deferred = $q.defer();
                isPromisePending = true;
                debugger;
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: envService.endPoint + 'delaycode'
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                })
                .then(function successCallback(response){
                    result = response.data;
                    isPromisePending = false;
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                },
                 function errorCallback(response) {
                     isPromisePending = false;
                    deferred.reject(response.data);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
```

If I set up the headers manually it works, but I don't want to have to do it in every service.  This works:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post.Authorization = "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("adal.idtoken");
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("adal.idtoken");
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I haven't set `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('ProtectedResourceInterceptor');` statement, and all code just like the example at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js, and I configured the endpoints for the cors calls, the Adal's interceptor worked fine on my side. Could you try again?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that adal.js isn't recognizing the URL you're sending the request to as a "backend request", so it's not attempting to inject the token automatically. See the logic here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L843-L844

The [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/todoListSvc.js#L6) uses relative URLs, that should work fine.

If you don't want to use the heuristics of adal.js you should be able to explicitly add your URLs via the `endpoints` parameter: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js#L21-L26

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line.

```
httpProvider.interceptors.push('ProtectedResourceInterceptor');
```

This is already being called inside the adal library init method.

```
  if (httpProvider && httpProvider.interceptors) {
                        httpProvider.interceptors.push('ProtectedResourceInterceptor');
                    }
```

Try removing this line and see if it works.